# Segmentation fault before any operation (declaration/use section)

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a fortran code that is perfectly working on my Imac using gfortran as a compiler.

However recently i switched to another computer where i have access to ifort compiler.

The program is compiled correctly, however when i run the code i get Segmentation fault before any execution, so it must be something in the declaration of variables or in the use statement that is causing this error.
Any idea? I'm completely clueless...

I'm posting the declaration section of my code:

```
program Stokes

 use ziggurat_m
 use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

 implicit none

 !Include the FFTW library:
 include 'fftw3.f'



 !Start declaration of variables:

 integer, parameter ::  Nelem = 64  ,&
                       npart = 20  ,&
                       nsims = 10000  ,&
                       nphi = 1

 !Double precision parameters:
double precision, parameter :: pi= 4.0*atan(1.0)

!Mesh variables:                       
double precision :: mesh(nelem,nelem,nelem,3), invmesh(nelem,nelem,nelem,3)

double precision :: xp(3,npart), sigma(npart), fpart(3,npart),     fspread(nelem,nelem,nelem,3), tpart(3,npart),&
                 tspread(nelem,nelem,nelem,3),stress_part(5,npart), stress_spread(nelem,nelem,nelem,3)

double precision, allocatable :: partgaussenv(:,:), vec_partgaussenv(:,:,:)

double complex :: fhat(nelem,nelem,nelem,3), uhat(nelem,nelem,nelem,3), fluctstresshat(nelem,nelem,nelem,3,3)
double precision :: u(nelem,nelem,nelem,3), up(3,npart), omegap(3,npart),   rate_defp(5,npart)
double precision :: fluctstress(nelem,nelem,nelem,3,3)


double precision, parameter :: kbt = 1.0 ,&   !kBT
                               deltat = 1.0   !deltat

integer, allocatable :: cicle_array(:,:,:)
integer :: max_size

integer :: seed
double precision :: seed_rnd

integer :: i,j,k,l
logical :: test=.true. 

!optimization timing variables:
double precision :: start, finish, start1, finish1, transf_time, start2,     finish2, transf_time2

!Postprocessing variables:
double precision :: diffcoeff
double precision :: up_msq(3)
```

Comment: likely due to your large static arrays.  Try making `fluctstress` (etc ) allocatable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649155/stack-overflow-in-fortran-program/1650805#1650805