# Stack overflow when calling subroutines

Tags: fortran

When I call a subroutine within a code I receive the message Stack overflow. 
Notice: program was fully working with no message at all. It started suddenly when I ran it again few days later.

```
do i=1,npop
        do j=1,nvar
          call random_number(r1)
          call random_number(r2)
          poptemp(i,j)=poptemp(i,j)+bheta*r1*(pop(i,j)-poptemp(i,j))+  &
                                    bheta*r2*(pbest(j)-poptemp(i,j))
          Pk(j)=poptemp(i,j)
        end do

        call RSM(Pk,varmin,varmax,obj,lda,x,y,z,mi,sigma2,Rinv,cvg)
        objcont=objcont+1
    ftemp(i)=obj

 end do
```

**The Call RSM(....) statement gives me the error message.**

forrtl: severe (170): Program Exception - stack overflow

```
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source
RSM_25.exe         00CC6947  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
RSM_25.exe         00CC3A8D  _MAIN__                   129  RSM_teste25.f90
RSM_25.exe         00CC8412  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
RSM_25.exe         00CC6DDF  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
RSM_25.exe         00CC6C0F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       75E56359  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          77947B74  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          77947B44  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Comment: Sorry, it is completely impossible to tell what is going wrong with the information given here. Please provide a short but complete program that shows the problem, and tell us how you are compiling it.

Comment: Likely, there is nothing wrong with your program, you just do not have enough stack space. Check out this post: [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649155/stack-overflow-in-fortran-program)

Comment: Check the signature of RSM - have you got the parameters in the correct order and are all the parameters of the expected type?

Comment: If Dan Sp. is right, a quick and simple fix might be to use the `/heap-arrays:XYZ` [compiler flag](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-heap-arrays) to force the compiler to allocate arrays larger than XYZ kiB on heap rather than on stack.